# sphinx raises reference exception

Tags: python-sphinx

I am using autofunction to document the following function in python:

```
def my_func(param1, param2):
"""
:param param1: desc1
:param param2: desc2
:raises :exc:`MyException`: desc3
"""
# the function
```

The problem is that I can't reference :exc:`MyException` inside the  raises block.