# Sphinx, reference to class in function docstring

Tags: reference, python-sphinx, docstring

**EDIT:** First of all I am sorry, I found out that this is a duplicate of unanswered question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850423/sphinx-raises-reference-exception). 
I added full example code and image of the html output.

I use sphinx for documenting a python project. I have a function that raises multiple custom Exceptions. So my code looks like this:

```
class MyException1(Exception):
    """
    My Exception 1
    """
    pass


class MyException2(Exception):
    """
    My Exception 2
    """
    pass

def process_finished(path):
    """
    Description

    :param path: Path to the finished file
    :type path: string
    :returns: None
    :raises MyException1: My first exception
    :raises MyException2: My second exception
    """
    print(path)

def process_finished2(path):
    """
    Description

    :param path: Path to the finished file
    :type path: string
    :returns: None
    :raises: :exc:`MyException1`: My first exception
    :raises: :exc:`MyException2`: My second exception
    """
    print(path)
```

The output as html then looks like this:
[image: output html]

My concern is the *Raises* block of functions `process_finished`  and `process_finished2`. I would like the docs to look like in the first function, but the exception being a reference as in  `process_finished2`.

I guess it is just not possible with sphinx by default, though this does work without any referencing for return type. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do your custom exceptions have docstrings?

Comment: Yes, I can make the reference normally. It just breaks formatting of the Raises section if I do it like this.

Comment: What exactly happens? Your first example (without the `:class` markup) works for me. Perhaps you can post a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I added a full dummy code with image of the output. Hope it explains it more clearly.